# Leap Motion Coordinate System, Translations and Interaction Box with Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am working on a Unity leap motion desktop project using latest versions of Orion and unity prefabs package. I have created a simple scene pretty much identical to the one in Desktop Demo scene. (pair of capsule hands and a simple object you can poke and move around)

https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/devguide/Leap_Coordinate_Mapping.html

This article covers all of the issues I am currently facing but so far, I was unable to implement these solutions in my project.

When moving hands from the maximum range of the camera for example left to right or any other direction, this only translates to a portion of available screen space, in other words, a user will never be able to reach out to the edges of a screen with their hands. From my understanding, the tracking info provided in millimetres by the camera is somehow translated into units that Unity can understand and process. I want to change that scale.

From the article, "You also have to decide how to scale the Leap Motion coordinates to suit your application (i.e. how many pixels per millimetre in a 2D application). The greater the scale factor, the more affect a small physical movement will have." - This is exactly what I want to do in Unity.

Additionally, even being able to what I think was a successful attempt at normalisation of coordinates using the InteractionBox, I am unsure what to do with the results. How or rather, where do I pass these values so that it will display the hands in an updated position.

Comment: In case the above post is chaotic, essentially, how do I increase sensitivity of hand movement in Unity with Orion version 3.2